# Unity C# Checking bool takes last option

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do something if a Gameobject is active or not (trying to do the pause option) so i do that if Menu 1, that its the pause menu, its active it takes a static bool called pause and sets it to true, and if menu 1 is hidden it is false.

I have too menuoptions, that if u click it it is above this initial menu.

I start with the menu hidden, and i press scape. It works, but when i try to hide it again it doesnt work. Any help?

```
void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && !menuoptions.activeSelf){
            OpenMenu();
        }
    }
void OpenMenu(){
        if (menu1.activeSelf){
            menu1.SetActive(false);
            PJController.pause = true;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }

        if (!menu1.activeSelf){
            menu1.SetActive(true);
            PJController.pause = false;
            ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta = new Vector2 ( -1f , ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta.y );
            Cursor.visible = false;
            StartCoroutine ( ExpandRoutine ( ) );
        }


}

    //Just an animation for opening the menu.
public IEnumerator ExpandRoutine ( ) {
    while ( ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta.x < 544f ) {
        ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (  ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta.x + speed * Time.deltaTime ,  ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta.y);
        yield return null;
    }
    ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta = new Vector2 ( 544f , ScrollTransformMenu1.sizeDelta.y );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're doing here:

```
   if (menu1.activeSelf){
        menu1.SetActive(false);
       // snip...
    }

    if (!menu1.activeSelf){
        menu1.SetActive(true);
        // snip
    }
```

Both of these will always be executed. In the first `if`, you're setting the menu inactive. In the second `if`, you're checking if the menu is inactive, then setting it active. Any chance you meant to use an `else` instead of a second `if`?

Set some breakpoints in your debugger and step through it.